# Writing square root in cplusplus

Tags: c++

I just want to ask how to write the formula of in c++:

(square root of 2K over M)
i don't know how. please help.

I am going to find the mass using the formula of Kinetic Energy which is K = 1/2 mv^2

i dont know how to put square root symbol in c++

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions only.

Comment: Answer below, but you might want to retitle the question to something less physical and more computational.

Answer (score 4):

Use `std::sqrt` to compute the square root.

Given `mass` and `energy` as numeric types, you can use use `std::sqrt(2.0 * energy / mass)` to compute the speed. I take care to write `2.0` to force the floating point overload of `std::sqrt` to be used, and to ensure that the division is **not** an integral one.

Take care that `mass` is not zero, or negative, else you'll get a NaN on a platform that uses IEEE754 floating point types.

Answer (score -1):

First include header file math.h

And then write the formula as 
int a = (2*k)/m;
V=sqrt (a);

Here sqrt() function is used for square root in above example it is square root of a